# How to resolve "GeoDataFrame object has not attribute..." error

Tags: python, dataframe, gis, geopandas

Repeatedly while coding (novice coder), I get the same error message when working with GeoDataFrames in geopandas: AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute XYZ.

Same error occurs at several points in code (seems almost every operation I attempt to implement).

```
    conflict_events = []
    for index, row in polys.iterrows():
        polygon = polys.geometry[0]
        subset = conflict[conflict.within(polygon)]
        # print(subset)
        conflict_events.append(subset)
        print(polys.conflict_events)
```

Error = AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'conflict_events'

polys is a shapefile. conflict is a point dataset.

```
    for index, row in val.iterrows():
        # print(type(row['val_mar19']))
        # print(type(polys_val.loc[index].count))
        val_calc = row['val_mar19'] / float(polys_val.loc[index]['count'])
        if not math.isnan(val_calc):
            val_calc = int(val_calc)
        polys.REFPOP.iloc[[polys.NAME_1 == row.NAME_1]] = val_calc
    polys.to_file("val_pop.shp")
    scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
    scaled_actual = scaler.fit_transform(output.row['simEnd'])
    scale_predicted = scaler.fit_transform(val.row['val_mar19'])
```

Error = AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute ''row'

val is a shapefile.

In both cases, same error. In first case, I am trying to loop through the polygons, determine how many points fall within each (count), and save that value to a new row "conflict_events." In the second case, I am trying to use sklearn to normalize the values in two rows (simEnd and val_mar19) from two shapefiles respectively (output and val) to 0-1. I believe I am handling something incorrectly when it comes to GeoDataFrames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't work withi GeoDataFrames per se, but with DataFrames.

In the first instance, you have made a list object called conflict_events. At the bottom you attempt to print that information but you have coded using "poly.conflict_events". 'poly' is the geodataframe object and it's attributes can be called by

```
poly.someattribute
```

Since there is no attribute conflict_events for poly, python throws an error.

You are doing a similar thing in the second example in the last line. val is a geodataframe object. 'row' are the values of a specific row of that object created by iterrows. 'val' doesn't have an attribute specifically called row.

Hope that helps.